# Setting an ErrorDocument 404 in .htaccess causes jQuery's AJAX call to never error

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

Alright, so I tried to use .htaccess to set up ErrorDocuments for various error codes. It works great, except that now, the following jQuery AJAX code will never run the error() function:

```
$.ajax({url: url, type: "GET", cache: false, error: function(){
 alert("Looking rather erroneous, are we?");
}, success: function(html){
 // ...
}
```

Any proposals? I think I know the reason why: .htaccess points all errors like so:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

And /error.php has the following:

```
<?php header("Location: /#error"); ?>
```

So when it transfers to index.php, it probably loses the 404 document status.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing a header along with your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({url: url, type: "GET", cache: false, headers: {'X-My-AJAX-Header': 'yes'}, error: function(){
 alert("Looking rather erroneous, are we?");
}, success: function(html){
 // ...
}
```

...which you can then detect in your `error.php`, to treat errors from AJAX requests differently:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_MY_AJAX_HEADER'])) {
    header('Status: 404');
} else {
    header("Location: /#error");
}
?>
```

You may have to experiment with that `$_SERVER` key. See also [`apache_request_headers`](http://php.net/apache_request_headers) if you're using Apache/mod_php.

**EDIT:**

The reason you need to do this is, as stated below, the `header("Location: /#error");` sends a 302 (redirect) header, which overrides the 404 (not found). You can't use the `Location:` header to redirect on a 404 (it only works on 3xx) and you can only send one status. JQuery will (correctly) only trigger the error callback on an error status; these are all 4xx.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)'s explanation of this is very good.

Comment: I changed header("Location: /#error"); to header("Location: /?error#error"); and then added an if() statement to the beginning of index.php that adds a 404 header if $_GET["error"] isset().

Answer (score 0):

Checking the headers in Chrome Developer Tools, Firebug, or a development proxy will show what's happening here: The 302 Found header set by sending a "Location:" header by PHP overrides the 404 error that would otherwise be sent.  As a result, no client (including search engines and also jQuery's AJAX request handler in this case), knows that an error occurred. As far as they're concerned the request was successful and picked up the intended content (after one redirect).

Sending a simpler 404 without redirect will result in more predictable behavior.